# Why is my array declaration incorrect?

Tags: bash, array

I'm trying to do some shizzle with SFTP and SSH but it would seem I'm getting hung up on super-simple array declaration.

According to [this](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html), I should be able to use the following syntaxes to create an array:

```
[bob in ~] ARRAY=(one two three)

[bob in ~] echo ${ARRAY[*]}
one two three

[bob in ~] echo $ARRAY[*]
one[*]

[bob in ~] echo ${ARRAY[2]}
three

[bob in ~] ARRAY[3]=four

[bob in ~] echo ${ARRAY[*]}
one two three four
```

The part from that for me to focus on is this line:

```
[bob in ~] ARRAY=(one two three)
```

I tried replicating in my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
USERS=("user1" "user2" "user3")
PASSES=("pass1" "pass2" "pass3")

for i in ${!USERS[@]}; do
    echo ${PASSES[i]};
done
```

Running this (using `sh script.sh`) outputs:

> script.sh: 2: script.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Why is my array declaration incorrect? Is the guide just wrong?

I know I can use:

```
declare -a ARRAY
```

and then append to it, but I like the idea of using a one-liner wherever possible.

Thanks,

Comment: Found a dupe for my question ^^ :)

Comment: Sure, but the loop is still wrong...

Comment: @steeldriver Quoting `${PASSES[i]}`, obviously, and using `printf`, since it's a password that could contain _anything_.